# jQuery UI Autocomplete with FCBKcomplete/AutoSuggest/TokenInput styling

Tags: css, styling, jquery-ui-autocomplete, fcbkcomplete

I am currently using the jQuery autocomplete feature. Functionality wise, it works awesome!
But in terms of styling (in addition to theme roller), I would really like to see something like
http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ and
http://www.emposha.com/demo/fcbkcomplete/

I am still reading the codes in these plugin, so that I can achieve similar look/behavior. Ideally, I would rather stick with jQuery UI library than switching over to other plugin. How would one go about making this happen?

Answer (score 0):

EVERYTHING in Jquery is style-able via CSS.  If you want to achieve a different look, simply build CSS that will override the default styles.  If there's a specific style you're trying to achieve, I'm sure quite a few of us would be happy to help with ideas to make them happen.

BTW, the emposa.com site link you provided is completely dead.  I'm hoping you're not trying to achieve THAT style....